# Health and Wellbeing system tree type program

Tags: python

I have been asked by school to code the following:

When a person has a problem with their health that they deem to not be critical, automated troubleshooting programs are available to help them at some doctors surgeries.
If a health issue occurs, then a troubleshooting process can be used before the person is passed onto a doctor, with the user responding to a series of questions that lead to a solution or advice.

For example, a conversation might proceed as follows:​

- System: ‘Do you have a rash?’
- Person: ‘No’
- System: ‘Are you suffering from a shortness of breath?’
- Person: ‘No’
- System: ‘Are you suffering from dizzy spells?’ …

Not all of the questions need to have yes or no responses but each response will need to lead to a supplementary question or a solution.
Analyse the requirements for this system and design, develop, test and evaluate a program to interrogate the user about the nature of the illness, leading to a solution or advice to be passed onto a medical professional. You will need to create a suitable troubleshooting tree. This should be a demonstration version of the system with at least 10 possible solutions, but need not include an exhaustive list of potential problems or solutions.

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
#Welcome messages
def healthsystem ():
    print("")

    print("Welcome to the Health and Wellbeing System")

    #Name Validation 
    while True:
        name = str(input("Enter Name: "))
        if name.isalpha(): #checks if the name is a string
            break
        elif name.isdigit(): #checks if the name contains a number
            print("You can't enter a number as your name!")
            print("")
        else: #checks if the user inputs a symbol e.g.(/ . , !)
            print("This character cannot be used in your name!")
            print("")



    q1= input("Do you have a fever? [Y/N] ")
    if q1 == "y" or q1 == "Y":
        q2=input("Do you have blurry vision? [Y/N] ")
    if q1 == "n" or q1 == "N":
        q2=input("Have you grown fangs?")

    if q2 == "y":
        q3=input("Do you crave human blood? [Y/N]")
    if q2 == "n":
        q3=input("Do you crave human flesh? [Y/N]")


    if q3 == "y":
        print("You are a zombie!")
    if q3 == "n":
        print("You are showing potential signs of a zombie")

 while True:
    healthsystem()
```

I was hoping that you could help me to code some of this or give me a starting point.

Comment: What are your attempts at it? This is not a code writing service. Please read [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that you want to do is to factor out the "UI" code - the part that asks a question and returns the user's answer - into a distinct function, something like:

```
def ask(question):
   while True:
      answer = input("{}? [Y/N] ".format(question)).strip().lower()
      if answer in ("y", "n"):
          return answer
      print("Please answer Y or N")
```

Now for the core of the question: you need to think in term of data structure. What you want here is to build a data structure that can model your "decisions tree", IOW that stores questions and for each question two sub-elements - one for a "Yes" answer and one for the "No" answer -, these elements being either new questions or solutions. The obvious data type here is a tree - that's what we just described, didn't we ? -, with the very first question as root.

Once you have this, you just have to traverse your tree, selecting the left or right branch depending on the answer to the current question. If the selected branch has childrens, it's another question, so you ask the next question, lather rinse repeat. Else - if it's a leaf node - you have a solution, you print it and you're done.

You can easily build such a tree using either nested `dicts` or nested `tuples` - heres a `dict`-based example:

```
tree = {
   "input": "Do you want to become a programmer",
   "n" : {
      "input" : "You're not at the right place"
      },      
   "y" : {
      "input": "Do you know anything about data structures",
      "n": {
        "input" : "So learn about it"
       },
      "y": {
        "input" : "So use it"
        },
     },
  }
```